# How do I create a Guid with Infopath Script?

Tags: infopath

In infopath script (J), how do I generate a GUID?

This is my current and comletely hacked (and horrid) method.

```
var getGuid = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
getGuid.Open("SELECT NewId()", mySqlConn);
var guid = getGuid.Fields(0).Value;
```

There has to be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getGUID()
{
    return new ActiveXObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID;
}
```

Your form will need to be Full Trust otherwise you will get a script error.